# How enable use GeForce MX150?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, system-settings

I have notebook Xiaomi Mi Pro 15.6. The notebook has GeForce MX150 graphic adapter. I enable Nvidia driver in additional drives,
[image]

but when I go to Settings -> Details -> About I see:
Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)

[image: ,]

How enable GeForce MX150 ?

Answer (score 3):

Given than you installed the drivers using the additional drivers tab, you should have already installed Nvidia Settings. Look in there for the PRIME Profiles menu and use it to switch between the two cards as shown in the image:

[image]

Alternatively, you can open your terminal and write the command

```
prime-select query
```

to check which of the cards is your system using, and the commands

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

or

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

to change between the two cards and then restart the session.

Answer (score 1):

Here is explained the right answer, i hope it helps you.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: It does not help me, after install driver I can see the same picture. Device uses internal graphic

Comment: What does `prime-select query` return?
I have the same NVidia graphics card, just got it working by selecting nvidia-driver-418

Answer (score 1):

When it is about Nvidia, it is better to install the proprietary driver.
Here is a detailed answer:

To remove the installed Nvidia drivers, run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo apt remove nvidia-*  
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then, check which is the recommended driver for your Nvidia card by running:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If you want to install the driver automatically, run :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If you want to install a specific driver, run:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-<driver number>
```

Once the installation is finished, run `prime-select query` to check which graphic card is being used by your device.
If you want to change the graphic card used by your PC, run : `sudo prime-select <intel/ nvidia>`; choose between Nvidia and Intel graphic cards.
After that, restart your PC to apply changes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a HP Spectre x360 and I solved it by disabling secure boot in the BIOS.

Comment: Are you sure this is what fixed the problem?  The only reason I could see for that would be that the NVidia drivers could not be loaded due to code signing forced by secure boot.
I'm not saying you're wrong, just that I find it highly unlikely.